# Binding to command in control works only one time after triggering visualstudio hot reload feature

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have built a control representing a dropdown menu.
It accepts the following parameter:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownCommandsDictProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(DropDownCommandsDict),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, IAsyncRelayCommand>>),
        typeof(ToggleButtonDropDownControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, IAsyncRelayCommand>>(),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, IAsyncRelayCommand>> DropDownCommandsDict
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, IAsyncRelayCommand>>)GetValue(DropDownCommandsDictProperty);
        set => SetValue(DropDownCommandsDictProperty, value);
    }
```

The dropdown control works with an ToggleButton and a Popup to display its Commands, see screenshot
[Screenshot of dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe61h.png)

The bindings are defined as following.

In the dropdown control:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.RecipeDropDownCommandsDict, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=1}}">
```

The use of the component:

```
<sharedControls:ToggleButtonDropDownControl 
    Caption="..."
    DropDownCommandsDict="{Binding Path=DataContext.RecipeDropDownCommandsDict, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=1}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

The bindings works only one time after editing itself and the visual studio hot reload feature ist triggered.

**If I move the code out of the component and paste it directly into the Xaml everything works as expected and the commands are executed**

I walked the visual tree up and down to find the error causing this problem. The dropdown is outside the visual tree - at the bottom of it to be specific.

I suspect the error is somewhere in the DependencyProperty stated at the top of this question.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit: Turned out a style setter has overritten the clickable control and therefore its ability to handle the event properly, the hot reload feature just made it tricky to understand/debug.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out a style setter has overritten the clickable control and therefore its ability to handle the event properly, the hot reload feature just made it tricky to understand/debug.

Comment: could you tell us how you solved the problem?

Comment: Of course, with the help snoop (https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) by selecting your application and clicking on the googles button to open the inspect window.After that by pressing [strg] + [shift] you can select a node in the visual tree of your application. Now you can watch and monitor all events walking though the visual tree up.